# LayoutManager for RecycleView for what?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I can not find an explanations why we need to set `LayoutManager` for `RecycleView`.
Someone can explain ?

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Actually have you read about LayoutManager? if no please read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager)

Comment: Please read about Layout manager over [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager

Answer (score 2):

The **LinearLayoutManager** allows you to specify an **orientation**, just like a normal LinearLayout would.

Here is the doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager

> **Note** you can use `RecyclerView` with the `GridLayoutManager` as well

Comment: He is not asking what **Linear**LayoutManager is for, but layout managers in general. Your answer does not answer this. Please update it

Comment: @TimCastelijns please read question properly sir.. he is asked **why we need to set `LayoutManager` for `RecycleView`**...i answered correctly...if you want add some point please edit my answer or give new answer as you own...

Comment: you did not answer correctly. You answered in the context of LinearLayoutManager only

Comment: @TimCastelijns please check my answer carefully i already given offical doc also....i hope this is enoungh.

Comment: yes you gave a link, but only a link for LinearLayoutManager. Your answer is extremely minimal, does not answer the question "why do we need to set layout managers" and explains nothing about GridLayoutManager besides mentioning that it exists, so no, your answer is not enough. Just because 3 people upvote your answer does not mean it is automatically a good answer

Answer (score 2):

One of the best examples of using LayoutManager is to create a horizontal `RecycleView`

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 1):

The layout manager takes responsibility for positioning your items in the view. It calculates the size and position of each item.

Answer (score 1):

It’s main work is to manage the layout for the large data-set provided by adapter. It positions each item views into it’s appropriate position in the RecycleView. Also, It re-uses the views that are no longer visible to the user. During this, It may ask the adapter to replace the contents of that view with a different element from data-set. Recycling(or Re-using) views in this manners improves performance a lot since there is no need to create extra views and perform costly operations like findViewById().